# AWS Elasticesearch from ios application

Tags: ios, rest, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS ES for the search on my iOS application. As of now, I use the Rest API for the serving the search queries to the application. The app calls the Rest API and my python server searches to serve the requests. I want to eliminate this Rest API server and want to implement the interaction between iOS and AWS ES directly. AWS iOS SDK does not provide service for ES. What shall I do for that?

I have looked into these resources but did not get much clarity,

[Elasticsearch access policy - allow read from clients and read/write from Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623444/elasticsearch-access-policy-allow-read-from-clients-and-read-write-from-node-j)

[How to secure access to AWS Elasticsearch from a mobile application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44253143/how-to-secure-access-to-aws-elasticsearch-from-a-mobile-application)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of AWS Cognito, User Pools and Federated Access to provide fine grained access to AWS resources to your set of users.

Read more at this link: [Secure API Access with Amazon Cognito Federated Identities, Amazon Cognito User Pools, and Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/secure-api-access-with-amazon-cognito-federated-identities-amazon-cognito-user-pools-and-amazon-api-gateway/)

I won't recommend doing this though, **especially for elastic search** cause if any of the temporary credentials (STS tokens) are stored in an in-secure place (not a keychain), users will be able to delete or create indices on your elastic search cluster, as AWS does not provide fine grain control over the APIs exposed by elasticsearch itself.

To solve this problem, you can use API Gateway as a proxy to only the search endpoints of the indices you want to allow your clients to be able to search. You do **not** need a Lambda function or any EC2 instance in the middle to achieve this.

Comment: What should be the recommended way? Shall I continue with the current structure? what is the ideal solution from your side to serve the purpose here? @yeshodhan

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: +1 for the API Gateway solution. Make yourself a custom SDK to give you what you want while protecting your ES instance from malicious activity.